# appendChild using a foreach statement

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

This code is only appending the last integer in the for statement. I'm trying to append $root_text for each value in the for statement. Is $root_text supposed to be an array? I'm only appending 1 value with $root->appendChild($root_text)

The code:

```
 <?php
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'iso-8859-1');

$root = $doc->createElement('test');
$doc->appendChild($root);

for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {

    $root_text = $doc->createTextNode($i);

}

$root->appendChild($root_text);

print $doc->saveXML();
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently assigning a new value to `$root_text` each time through the loop, retaining (and ultimately appending) only the node from the final iteration. Why not simply `appendChild` directly in the loop?

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $test = $doc->createElement('test');
    $test->appendChild($doc->createTextNode($i));
    $root->appendChild($test);
}
```

Comment: This still does not create a test tag for each value in the for statement.

Comment: @RPM - I didn't realize that was a requirement. Just do that part in the loop body, too. See my edit.

Comment: Where do I put this for statement? I'm getting an error:  Call to undefined function appendChild()

Answer (score -2):

What you're doing there is replacing $root_text with $doc->createTextNode($i) on each cycle.
What you may want to do is make $root_text an array.

```
<?php
    $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'iso-8859-1');

    $root = $doc->createElement('test');
    $doc->appendChild($root);

    $root_text = array(); //always initialize arrays
    for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
        $root_text[] = $doc->createTextNode($i);
    }

    //this will output the contents of $root_text so you can examine it
    print_r($root_text);

    $root->appendChild($root_text);

    print $doc->saveXML();
?>
```

Comment: I just tested your code. It outputs an array but does not append them as a node in the XML document.

Comment: This is the error: Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to DOMNode::appendChild() must be an instance of DOMNode, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\append_child.php on line 15